# MQ TLS communication with Weblogic using foreign JMS

Tags: ssl, weblogic, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to MQ from weblogic 12c server using foreign JMS( using .bindings file). But not able to figure out where to configure cipher suite in Weblogic for SSL/TLS communication. I know how to do it in java code. But have no clue how to specify it in Weblogic resources.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You put the MQ SSL/TLS information in the bindings file.

Comment: Thanks Roger for your reply. Do you have idea about how to put that information in binding file.  I tried something like below in the bindings file but it has not worked.  TestQCF/RefAddr/29/Content=hostname (50501) sslCipherSuite(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256)

Comment: Don't do it manually!! Use either MQ Explorer or JMSAdmin command-line tool to edit/update the bindings file.